# how to pass list of arguments to VM command line

Tags: java, jvm, command-line-arguments

I want to pass 2 dynamic VM argument, how?

to pass one dynamic argument i use:

```
 java -Dxxxxxxxx=xxxx main
```

but how to pass more than 1 argument.

Thanks.

Comment: `-Dproperty1=value1 -Dproperty2=value2` etc.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: this should have been the answer.

Comment: i use the following java -cp . -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./loginmodules.properties -Djava.security.policy=.
chp02.policy -Djava.security.manager chp02.Chp02Main  , but only 1st argument is execute

Answer (score 0):

From [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

**-Dproperty=value**

- Sets a system property value.
- **If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the string in double quotation marks**:

`java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass`

In your command line:

```
java -cp . -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./loginmodules.properties -Djava.security.policy=. chp02.policy -Djava.security.manager chp02.Chp02Main
```

the second argument `-Djava.security.policy=. chp02.policy` contains a <kbd>space</kbd>.

You need to enclose with <kbd>"</kbd> or correct the argument if the <kbd>space</kbd> is a mistake.

Comment: thanks, the space was added by mistake in my question details but it's  without space when i execute the command.

Comment: if execute the command: java -cp . -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=./chp02.policy chp02.Chp02Main, the i get the Exception : 
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission" "cr
eateLoginContext.chp02"), although i sued in the policy file the row : permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.*";

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a **new** question.