# passing Jvm properties (via -D) that contain spaces

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

I have a docker application that runs a java jar inside from the command line. I have set up the docker container to pass through "other java options", and in this case I would like to pass the following:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 128, DSA keySize < 128, EC keySize < 128
```

I was hoping to be able to pass it in via -Djdk.etc but the spaces seem to really throw things off. With the spaces java complains it doesn't know what to do with the MD5 and later ("Error: Could not find or load main class MD5,". Without the spaces, I get errors about `keySize<` being an unknown main class.

Can someone please help me with the proper way to pass this parameter in? I have tried surrounding the whole thing in quotes yet the results are the same.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214392/passing-a-space-separated-system-property-via-a-shell-script-doesnt-work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551755/7605325

Comment: man I looked up and down SO for anything resembling my question. Sorry! I put in both @talex's answer and the accepted answer in the link mariusz2108 commented, and it seems to all be resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should surround only variable value `-Dvar="a < b"` works for me.

Comment: All my -D properties are inside a UNIX variable, i tried using
MY_OVERIDES="$MY_OVERIDES -Dvar=\"a < b\" "
It doesn't work after that. When i echo $MY_OVERRIDES, it looks ok.
What to do here?

Comment: Try `MY_OVERIDES='$MY_OVERIDES -Dvar="a < b" ' `

Comment: That won't work, because `MY_OVERIDES` won't be expanded in single-quote strings.

Comment: Also, not related to Docker, but to Java and its crappy command line parsing: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57271

Answer (score 1):

Found a better explanation here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2015-March/001768.html

The two options suggested were.

```
$ java -jar benchmarks.jar -jvmArgs "-Dx=12 -Dy=\"one two\""
$ java -jar benchmarks.jar -jvmArgs "-Dx=12" -jvmArgs "-Dy=one two"
```

Tried the 2nd version with Maven too. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of java (Idk since when, but at least it works with jdk17) allow passing argument files (using '@') containing the jvm options instead of adding the jvm options directly

```
echo '-Djdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms="MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 128, DSA keySize < 128, EC keySize < 128"' > /opt/jvmargs

java @/opt/jvmargs -Dother=arg -cp '.' ...
```